# steady timer asio boost

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Why doesn't my timer expire after 1 second but waits for 10 seconds?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    int count = 0;
    boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(10));

    t.async_wait([&t](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        t.expires_at(t.expiry() + boost::asio::chrono::seconds(9));
    });

    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It should take "exactly" 10 seconds: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/589690f5eba264a8)**

```
boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(10));
```

That's where you set the expiry in relative amount (`duration`) from `now()`.

The second "instruction":

```
t.expires_at(t.expiry() + boost::asio::chrono::seconds(9));
```

Would increase the expiry by another 9 seconds, relative to the original 10s deadline. However, you only give that instruction once the original 10s delay has completed. So it has no effect at all, unless you start another `[async_]wait` on the timer.

---

#### Modernize, Simplify, and Understand!

Instead of deprecated `io_service`, consider `io_context`.

Instead of `asio::chrono` consider `std::chrono`.

Instead of `chrono::seconds` consider `std::chrono_literals`.

Instead of `t.expires_at(t.expiry() + duration)` consider `t.expires_from_now(duration)`. Of course, beware that this might not mean the same thing depending on how much latency is accrued in completion handlers *or* whether cancellation is used.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0244ca0b1ab77c69)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;

int main() {
    asio::io_service io;
    asio::steady_timer t(io, 1s);
    int count = 0;

    std::function<void(error_code)> handler;

    auto const start = now();
    handler = [&](error_code ec) {
        std::cout << "at " << (now() - start) / 1.0ms
                  << "ms handler: " << ec.message() << '\n';
        if (ec.failed())
            return;

        if (count++ < 10) {
            t.expires_from_now(500ms);
            t.async_wait(handler);
        }
    };

    t.async_wait(handler);

    io.run();
    std::cout << "at " << (now() - start) / 1.0ms << " Done\n";
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
at 1000.31ms handler: Success
at 1500.66ms handler: Success
at 2000.82ms handler: Success
at 2500.97ms handler: Success
at 3001.2ms handler: Success
at 3501.43ms handler: Success
at 4001.64ms handler: Success
at 4501.88ms handler: Success
at 5002.12ms handler: Success
at 5502.36ms handler: Success
at 6002.59ms handler: Success
at 6002.66 Done
```